# App Clip with EXPO React Native not found the app entry point module name?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, expo, apple-appclips

I'm trying to integrate the App Clip feature in my application developed in react native with EXPO.

I state that I have already integrated the App Clip feature in a React Native project without EXPO and I have not had any major problems while with expo I have a problem that I cannot solve.

I get this error in main.m file:

> Invariant Violation: "ReactNativeTest" has not been registered. This can happen if:
>
> - Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
> - A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

I believe the problem is related to the ViewController.m file in this point:

```
// moduleName corresponds to the appName used for the
// app entry point in "index.js"
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc]
initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation moduleName:@"ReactNativeTest"
initialProperties:nil launchOptions:nil];
```

In a project without EXPO the moduleName for the app entry point in "index.js" is this

[image]

but in this case it doesn't work, do you have a solution?

Comment: How did you access native iOS files? Did you eject expo? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the solution by myself, if anyone needed I followed these steps:

In index.appclip.js I modified it from this:

```
import { AppRegistry, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import React from 'react';

const AppClip = () => (
  <View style={{
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#BFEFFF"
  }}>
    <Text style={{
      fontSize: 26,
      color: "#204080"
    }}>Hello React Native App Clip</Text>
  </View>
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => AppClip);
```

to this:

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import React from 'react';

const AppClip = () => (
  <View style={{
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#BFEFFF"
  }}>
    <Text style={{
      fontSize: 26,
      color: "#204080"
    }}>Hello React Native App Clip</Text>
  </View>
);

registerRootComponent(AppClip);
```

and the moduleName for the app entry point in "index.js" is "main" so i modified ViewController.m like this:

```
// moduleName corresponds to the appName used for the
// app entry point in "index.js"
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc]
initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation moduleName:@"main"
initialProperties:nil launchOptions:nil];
```