# How to build AppClip with Expo?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, apple-appclips

I am trying to build an App Clip for my RN Expo App.

Is there a way for doing it without ejecting? (I assume not, but thought it was worth asking)?

Thanks.

P.S. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68214382/app-clip-with-expo-react-native-not-found-the-app-entry-point-module-name) post, but not sure how it can be done without eject.

Comment: I believe you would *have to* eject. A managed app wouldn't be able to include a separate target like this.

Comment: Even if I have exclusively app clip target, I still don’t think I can do it…

Answer (score 1):

These days there is a project that allows you to do this:

https://github.com/bndkt/react-native-app-clip

`react-native-app-clip` is an Expo Config Plugin. Config plugins allow you to add native code to a Managed Expo app. The config plugin will make the necessary changes to the native project during the build process.

From the README:

## react-native-app-clip

> **Warning**
> Starting with version 0.0.35, react-native-app-clip requires **Expo SDK 48** and **React Native 0.71**.

Expo Config Plugin that generates an App Clip for iOS apps built with Expo.

### Installation

Install it in your project:

```bash
npx expo install react-native-app-clip
```

In your app’s Expo config (app.json, or app.config.js), make sure that react-native-app-clip has been added to the list of plugins. You may optionally provide a name option, which will determine the display name of your App Clip in iOS. If you do not provide a value here, it will be your app’s name appended with " Clip".

```
"expo": {
  "name": "my-app",
  "plugins": [
      ["react-native-app-clip", { "name": "My App Clip" }]
  ]
}
```

### Additional parameters:

- **groupIdentifier** (string): Configures an app group to share data between App Clip and full app (see [Apple Developer Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-app-groups))
- **deploymentTarget** (string): Sets the deployment target for the App Clip. If you set this to "16.0", your App Clip can be 15 MB instead of 10 MB.
- **requestEphemeralUserNotification** (boolean): Enables notifications for the App Clip (see [Apple Developer Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/enabling_notifications_in_app_clips))
- **requestLocationConfirmation** (boolean): Allow App Clip access to location data (see [Apple Developer Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/confirming_the_user_s_physical_location))
- **appleSignin** (boolean): Enable "Sign in with Apple" for the App Clip
- **excludedPackages** (string[]): Packages to exclude from autolinking for the App Clip to reduce bundle size (see below).

### Native capabilities

```js
import {
  isClip,
  displayOverlay,
  setSharedCredential,
  getSharedCredential,
} from "react-native-app-clip";
```

**isClip()** allows determining whether the code is currently run within the App Clip and can be used to apply different content and behaviors for the full app and the App Clip.

**displayOverlay()** shows the native iOS banner to promote the full app within the App Clip (see [Apple Developer Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/recommending_your_app_to_app_clip_users)).

**setSharedCredential()** and **getSharedCredential()** allows sharing login data from the App Clip to the full app so that the user doesn't have to sign in again after downloading the full app (see [Apple Developer Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/sharing_data_between_your_app_clip_and_your_full_app)).

### Before building for the App Store

Please note that you must register a new App ID for the App Clip in your Apple Developer profile. Under "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles", go to “Identifiers”, click on the plus icon and select "App IDs" to create a new App ID. Select "App Clip" as the type and on the next screen, select your main app as the "Parent App ID" and enter Clip as the product name (it is crucial that the product name is "Clip" and nothing else. At the bottom of the page, Apple shows a preview of the App Clip Bundle ID. If your main app’s bundle ID is com.example.my-app, the App Clip Bundle ID should now be com.example.my-app.Clip.

### How to test the App Clip

App Clips can not be tested with Expo Go or expo-dev-client. The best two ways to test the App Clip seem to be the following:

#### Run in Simulator

Build the development client first by running `expo run:ios` and opening the app in Simulator. After doing this once, you can run `expo run:ios --scheme` and select the App Clip scheme ("...Clip") to open the App Clip. You could also add an extra script to your project’s package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "clip": "expo run:ios --scheme my-appClip"
}
```

Now you can simply type "npm run clip" in your terminal to open the App Clip.

#### Build App Clip with Xcode and open on a connected device

Run `expo prebuild -p ios` (see https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/expo-cli/#expo-prebuild) in your Expo project folder to generate the ios folder with all native sources. Then open the file `ios/my-app.xcworkspace` (with my-app being your app’s name) in Xcode. In your project, you should find two targets, one named like your app (e.g. "my-app") and one with a "Clip" suffix (e.g. "my-appClip"). For both targets, select a team in the "Signing & Capabilities" tab and make sure a signing certificate is selected by Xcode. Then, using the menu bar, select "Product", followed by "Scheme", where you should see two themes listed at the bottom of the menu, named after the two targets. Select the scheme that ends with "Clip". Now you can build and run the App Clip (using the menu bar via "Product" followed by "Run" or using the shortcut ⌘R).

#### Build for production using EAS Build and test via TestFlight

You can build your app and submit it to the App Store (see https://docs.expo.dev/build/introduction/) to test the App Clip using TestFlight. Refer to Apple’s developer docs about testing App Clips: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/testing_the_launch_experience_of_your_app_clip.